# Is it possible to use USB device plugged into my PC with Android Emulator on Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, usb

So I have a device that I need to attempt to communicate with through an android tablet or phone that connects through USB. The easiest way to debug and work out issues initially for me would be to plug this device into my PC and then somehow get that working through the emulator on Visual Studio. Is that possible, or is the only way I'm going to have to debug using the physical tablet and plug the USB into it?

Comment: I beg your pardon but its absolutely unclear what you want. Why would you want to run the emulator if you have a real device connected through USB?

Comment: @gustavogbc Because it would be significantly more work to try and connect the mobile device through bluetooth to my PC for debugging and connecting the USB to the  mobile device than to just boot up my PC and debug in visual studio through an emulator.

Comment: So @Demarini you simply want to debug your app in the emulator via Visual Studio, is that it?